# What is the amount of time a suspected woman needs to be secluded to be considered a Sotah?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, sotah-secluded-woman, yichud-seclusion, tractate-sotah

The Gemara lists a series of opinions (9 by my count) in [Sotah 4a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.4a?lang=bi) as to how long the amount of secluded time must be for a forewarned woman to be considered a potential *Sotah*.

Do we know which *Tanna* we *pasken* like and practically speaking, what amount of time this would be considered nowadays?

Comment: A starting point might be [Even Ha'ezer 178:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x8316) (courtesy of [Eyn Mishpat](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=4&format=pdf))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rambam Hilchos Sotah 1,2 Paskens like Rabbi Akiva the time for seclusion is to fry an egg and swallow it.

> שהתה עמו כדי טומאה שהוא כדי לצלות ביצה ולגמעה הרי זו אסורה על בעלה עד שתשתה מי המרים ויבדק הדבר

Kesef Mishna

> ומה שכתב שהוא כדי לצלות ביצה ולגמעה. ברייתא שם (דף ד') פלוגתא ופסק כר"ע:

Rashi Sotah 4a explains that with Sotah who has a history of being with this man we assume she was already been seduced before seclusion so we don't include seduction time :

> טומאה ביאה לחודה דאיכא למימר קודם הסתירה נתרצית לו

Tosfos says in the name of Yerushalmi we have to add on the time it takes for them to remove their vestige:

> בירושלמי כל אלין שיעורין אחר התרת סינר

The Minchas Yitchak 4,94 says this time of seclusion is 5 minutes,
Though the Dvar Halacha teshuva 11 says that this time is merely 35 seconds (one could assume this does not include removing vestiges)

Comment: Minchas yitzchak only says that to be machmir and be yotzei midei safek. even according to him, it should be longer. And I don't know who the devar halacha is but there is no way that you can roast an egg and swallow it in 35 seconds.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות do you mean 5 minutes is Machmir to make sure the Chosson satys with the Kalla in the Yichud room?

Comment: I mean I read the teshuvah and he says that this shitah would be hard to approximate, and the 5 minutes would be yotzei midei safek (it sounds like for a case of sotah, not yichud, and 5 minutes would be the **minimum** shiur)

Comment: note that many poskim understand the shiur of yichud in general to be longer than the shiur of yichud by a sotah, see R' Moshe's teshuvah.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות also remember tosfos who says taking of the clothes is not included in the time, i assume 35 seconds is probably when they are at such a stage

Comment: @user15464 good point.Perhaps include that in your answer.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות thanks! Do you possibly have a link to said R' Moshe teshuvah?

Comment: @alicht Even Haezer 4:65:22, some of which is cited below

Comment: והשיעור אם הוא גם בהאשה שנכנסה עמו הוא אסור בשיעור ביאה דהוא כדי לצלות ביצה ולגומעה דהלכה כר"ע בסוטה דף ד' אך צריך נוסף לזה קצת כשיעור לשכב ולפשוט מהבגדים עד כדי שיהא האפשריות לגלות את האברים וגם להלביש כמתחלה ואם מצד השכיבה נתלכלכו הבגדים לתקנם כמתחלה כדרך ההולכים בשוק, ואם אינו גס בה הא צריך עוד זמן כדי לרצותה דהא מה שבסתירה דסוטה דהוא אחר קינוי מסיק בסוטה דף ד' ע"א דלא בעי אלא שיעור ביאה בלא ארצותה פרש"י משום דאיכא למימר קודם הסתירה נתרצית לו, אבל הכא שנכנס לשם עם אשה שאינו מכירה ואף במכירה כשלא גס בה הרי ודאי יש להצריך גם כדי לארצותה שלזה לא שייך קביעות שיעור,

Comment: אבל אף לאשה כזו שדעתה קלה ביותר להתפתות הוא ודאי שיעור גדול טובא משיעור ביאה אף לפרוצות ואף לנשי נכריות דאף שאין חוששות לאיסורים אין מזנות לסתם אינשי אלא בפתוי וריצוי, ואף אם מכירה לקדשה הא צריך להשוות עמה בשכר ולשלם לה או ליתן לה משכון שג"כ הוא שיעור יותר גדול משיעור הביאה שהוא ודאי יותר מכל נסיעה ארוכה דאיכא במעלית אף דמשך כ"ה קומות

Comment: @רבות please see (and approve) my suggested edits where I include the Tosfos mentioned by user16456 that you told him to add into the answer. My edits get rejected quite often by the same people

Comment: @yosefkorn who is user16456? I don't see any comments from him here.

Comment: @רבות sorry I meant user15464 hard to remember the sequence of numbers...

Comment: @yosefkorn its literally there right in front of you, so there's no need to remember anything, but ok... ;) - I approved your edit.